# Reporting Services - SSRS: Personalizar mensajes de alerta

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, server, ssrs

actualment en mi reporte cuando un campo de parametros  se queda vacio envia un mensaje de alerta, esta validacion ya viene integrada desde el reporte  de manera nativa.

[image: imagen reporte con alerta]

Actualmente cuando meto valores y estos no son correctos me aparece un mensaje el cual me gustaria que fuera como en la primera imagen, pero personalizado por mi , devuelto desde el store procedure del reporte.

Esto se podria hacer ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]